# Google Play/App Store - Is there a way we can put message on the app before we take it down/ unpublish it?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

Before we unpublish/ remove our apps in Google store or App store we would like to put a message to users that we will take this down soon. Is there a way to show this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: nope,there is no chance but you can send notifications.

Comment: You could release an update to your app which shows an alert with this info. The only downside is that not all your users may download the update and also it may not work if your timeframe is tight.

Comment: Thanks @brahmyadigopula, yeah we are planning to notify them instead.

Comment: @Losiowaty that was our an option too.. but same reason, what if not all users download the update. Now I think the best option here, would be to be send notifications. Thanks for all your inputs :)